# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT getting data from 2 tables and linking table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use MySQL GROUP_CONCAT to aggregate data from 2 tables linked by a linking table. I would like to display useful data rather than just ids.

If I do the following query:

`SELECT pid, group_concat(vid) FROM bs_prod_vars GROUP BY pid`

I correctly get the following:

```
pid     group_concat(vid)
---------------------------------------
1       1,2,3,4,5,6
2       9,10,11,4,12,8,6,1,2,5,3,7
3       2,13,3,1,11,4,6,10,9,5,12,8,7
4       2,6,5,3,4,1
5       1,11,3,12,5,9,10,6,8,4,13,2,7
8       14
```

If I do this:

```
SELECT p.name, group_concat(v.name) 
FROM bs_products p, bs_variations v, bs_prod_vars pv 
WHERE pv.pid = p.id 
AND pv.vid = v.id 
GROUP BY p.name
```

I only get 2 rows as follows:

```
name                group_concat(v.name)
-------------------------------------------------------------
Test Product A      Pre-2012
Test Product B      2008 - 2010,2002 - 2012,From 2011,2002...
```

What am I doing wrong with my second query?

Comment: I'm not convinced you're doing anything wrong.  Can you show us sample data for your tables?

Comment: Unfortunately the data in the table is confidential and I can't share it (I replaced the real product names manually before pasting the results in). However, I can say that every unique pid and vid in the linking table bs_prod_vars relates to valid and existing id it's respective table bs_products/bs_variations, all of which have a non-empty name field.

Comment: Try without GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT first and if everything looks fine then group. The join is probably the problem

Comment: The query is working properly.  I'm afraid you are going to need to show us data if you want a definitive answer.

Comment: If it was working properly, shouldn't I be getting results exactly like the first set of results, but with each ID having been replaced with it's respective name from the linked table. eg I should still be getting 8 results.

Comment: Do various values of p.id share the same value of p.name?

Comment: @Kickstart Yes they do. I currently have 13 unique p.name values across a total of 19 records.

Comment: As you do a GROUP BY p.name, any records from p with the same value of name will be grouped together. If you want to avoid that try GROUP BY p.id